# How to get mutliple rows / columns from each cell?

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to get from `mydata_in` to `mydata_out_A` and `mydata_out_B`:

```
mydata_in <- data.frame(time=c(100,200,300,400))
mydata_out_A <- data.frame(time=c(100,100,100,200,200,200,300,300,300,400,400,400), time_new = c(101,102,103,201,202,203,301,302,303,401,402,403))
mydata_out_B <- data.frame(time=c(100,200,300,400), time_1 = c(101,201,301,401), time_2 = c(102,202,302,402), time_3 = c(103,203,303,403), time_4 = c(104,204,304,404))
```

by using `dplyr`.

I think I need somthing like `time + seq(1,3,1)`, but are not sure how to get multiple columns/rows from one cell.

In this case it makes not such a big difference whether I get `mydata_out_A` or `mydata_out_B`, because I should be able to transform them into each other e.g. with

```
mydata_out_B %>% gather(time_type, time_new, -time) %>% arrange(time, time_new)
```

However if in the future the number of outputs is not the same for every cell (for whatever reason) `mydata_out_A` had the advantage that the number of rows can be different for each input cell (time here).

Comment: Why do you have to use `dplyr` here?

Comment: @Spacedman: I want to. However if you have a different efficient solution, I am happy to hear about it :-).

Comment: Readability is the reason for using dplyr in most cases for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can do this with `base R`

```
stack(setNames(Map(`+`, mydata_in$time, list(1:3)), mydata_in$time))[2:1]
```

---

Or using `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
expand(mydata_in, time, time_New = 1:3) %>% 
               mutate(time_New = time + time_New)
```

Comment: microbenchmark tells me the tidy version takes four times as long as base.

Comment: Thanks, but I am not sure how this translates to arbitrary operations.

Comment: @Make42 This is based on the example you shared.  If it 1:6 or other, you have to change the `time_New = 1:6`

Comment: No, I mean something else. For example - just a couple of minutes later - now I need to make a fft after a group_by and have the data expanded into a new column. What I want to do is needed a lot in feature engineering: On an arbitrary vector (formed by group_by) we run a function that returns arbitrary vectors and that we want to store in the data.frame. In my question it the input was just a cell, but otherwise I deliberately state the question in general. I just wanted to give an example. Maybe that was not clear.

Comment: The answer to my last comment can be found at http://stackoverflow.com/q/43473524/4533188. I'll except the answer for the sake of my example, even if not for my original intended question ;-).