# How to a run function per group that return vector, not single value?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataset `data.frame(x=rnorm(100),group=c(rep('a',40),rep('b',60)))` that I want to analyse per group with dplyr. For example I want to use a `fft`. How can I produce run a function over each group which returns a sequence, not just value. If it was just a value I could summarize, which does not work here. I expect something like `data.frame(y=c(21,62,83,4,35,46,17,28), group=c(rep('a',5),rep('b',3)))` as output. I want to do it with dplyr if possible, because I think it improves readability.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can do with `unnest` after creating a `list` output with `summarise`.  It would be more easier to work with

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>%
    group_by(group) %>%
    summarise(value = list(fft(x))) %>%
    unnest()
```

Comment: Ah, the bonus fourth option. For one-dimensional output data (like FFT) I’d probably prefer this.

Answer (score 4):

There are essentially three options:

1. If you want to create a single summary value per group, use `summarize`.
2. If you want to transform each value per group, use `mutate`.
3. If you want to create a new table per group, use `do`.

The last option seems to fit your purpose best, if I understood you correctly. `do` is generally the most powerful of these options, but also the hardest to use. The general syntax is:

```
data %>%
    group_by(grouping_cols) %>%
    do(data_frame(col1 = some_transformation(.$x)))
```

For example:

```
iris %>%
    group_by(Species) %>%
    do(broom::tidy(lm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width, data = .)))
```

Comment: Thanks. That much I kind of gathered. Can you give an example how to use do?

Comment: Thanks! Very helpful now. Sorry, I could only check one answer.

Comment: @Make42 As I commented on the other answer, I think it’s actually a better solution for your problem anyway.